# React Carousal Component Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, carousel, web-component, react-component

I have included the react coverflow component to use a nice looking carousel in my project. It's loading fine but whenever I am clicking on the images it's showing me the following error shown in the screenshot:

[image]

I'm having the following code. Did any of you faced the same issue. **Note:** I've tried using npm install after installing the react coverflow component. After that also it's showing the same error. Is there any dependency issue? Any help?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Coverflow from 'react-coverflow';
import { StyleRoot } from 'radium';

class GetCarousel extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { isActive: 0 };
    }

    handleCarousal(e) {
        // console.log(e.currentTarget.id);
        // var text = e.currentTarget.id;
        var number = Number(e.currentTarget.id);
        this.setState({
            isActive: number
        });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                {/*<StyleRoot>*/}
                    <Coverflow width="100%" height="100%"
                        displayQuantityOfSide={5}
                        navigation={false}
                        enableScroll={true}
                        clickable={true}
                        active={this.state.isActive}
                        style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
                    >
                        <div
                          id="0"
                          onClick={this.handleCarousal.bind(this)}
                          onKeyDown={this.handleCarousal.bind(this)}
                          role="menuitem"
                          tabIndex="0"
                          style={{width: "100%", height: "100%"}}
                        >
                          <img
                            src='https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1'
                            alt='title or description'
                            style={{
                              display: 'block',
                              width: '100%',
                            }}
                          />

                        </div>
                        <div
                          id="1"
                          onClick={this.handleCarousal.bind(this)}
                          onKeyDown={this.handleCarousal.bind(this)}
                          role="menuitem"
                          tabIndex="1"
                        >
                            <img
                                src='https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2'
                                alt='title or description'
                                style={{
                                display: 'block',
                                width: '100%',
                                }}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div
                          id="2"
                          onClick={this.handleCarousal.bind(this)}
                          onKeyDown={this.handleCarousal.bind(this)}
                          role="menuitem"
                          tabIndex="2"
                        >
                            <img
                                src='https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3'
                                alt='title or description'
                                style={{
                                  display: 'block',
                                  width: '100%',
                                }}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div
                          id="3"
                          onClick={this.handleCarousal.bind(this)}
                          onKeyDown={this.handleCarousal.bind(this)}
                          role="menuitem"
                          tabIndex="3"
                        >
                            <img
                                src='https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4'
                                alt='title or description'
                                style={{
                                  display: 'block',
                                  width: '100%',
                                }}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div
                          id="4"
                          onClick={this.handleCarousal.bind(this)}
                          onKeyDown={this.handleCarousal.bind(this)}
                          role="menuitem"
                          tabIndex="4"
                        >
                            <img
                                src='https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5'
                                alt='title or description'
                                style={{
                                  display: 'block',
                                  width: '100%',
                                }}
                            />
                        </div>

                        {/*<img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/1" data-action="#one!"/>
                        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/2" data-action="#two!"/>
                        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/3" data-action="#three!"/>
                        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/4" data-action="#four!"/>
                        <img src="https://lorempixel.com/250/250/nature/5" data-action="#five!"/>*/}
                    </Coverflow>
                {/*</StyleRoot>*/}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default GetCarousel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove style from 'Coverflow'

```
<Coverflow width="100%" height="100%"
  displayQuantityOfSide={5}
  navigation={false}
  enableScroll={true}
  clickable={true}
  active={this.state.isActive}
>
```

Hope this will help to solve the problem

Comment: Tried your solution @Shiladitya but it's still showing the same error on click.